# AWS Cloudformation Container overrides

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I've created the `taskDefinition` using cloudformation and in the `ContainerDefinitions` I have `Command` to run the application with `daily` as parameter.

```
TaskDefinition: 
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    :
    :
    ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: test-report
      :
      :
      Command:
      - "./test_report"
      - daily
```

And I will want to create `TaskSchedule` for different frequency (eg. daily, weekly, monthly etc).

I know that in the AWS console I can go to `Edit Scheduled Task` > `Schedule Targets` > `Container override` and update the `command override` with `./test_report, weekly`.

But how to override command in cloudformation taskSchedule? Is that something to do in `Targets` property??

```
  TaskSchedule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      :
      Targets:
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

@toske's answer is now out-of-date.  You can set container overrides using the `Input` parameter to the target.  For example:

```
  LogicalResource:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: "a scheduled task"
      Name: my_scheduled_task
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(* * * * ? *)"
      State: ENABLED
      RoleArn: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
      Targets:
        - Id: fargate
          Arn: !GetAtt MyCluster.Arn
          RoleArn: !GetAtt MyTaskRole.Arn
          Input: '{ "containerOverrides": [{"name": "container", "command": [ "python", "manage.py", "my_awesome_management_command", "-a" ]}]}'
          EcsParameters:
             ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Within cloudformation template, CloudWatch event rule schedule is defined using cron expressions (or alternatively rate expressions). You can't override entrypoint from the rule itself, but you can create task definition for each of the report types (frequencies). I was unable to find task command override in the UI or the cloudformation documentation.

```
TaskDefinitionDaily: 
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
     # other task definition elements here
     ContainerDefinitions:
       # other container definitions here
        Command: 
          - "./test_report"
          - daily

TaskDefinitionWeekly: 
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
     # other task definition elements here
     ContainerDefinitions:
       # other container definitions here
        Command: 
          - "./test_report"
          - weekly

TaskDefinitionMonthly: 
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
     # other task definition elements here
     ContainerDefinitions:
       # other container definitions here
        Command: 
          - "./test_report"
          - monthly


# daily schedule at midnight UTC      
ScheduledRuleDaily: 
  Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "cron(00 00 * * ? *)"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets:
          - Arn: !GetAtt 
              - MyCluster
              - Arn
            RoleArn: !GetAtt 
              - ECSTaskRole
              - Arn
            Id: id1
            EcsParameters:
              TaskCount: 1
              TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinitionDaily


# weekly schedule at midnight UTC   
ScheduledRuleWeekly: 
  Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "cron(00 00 ? * 1 *)"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets:
          - Arn: !GetAtt 
              - MyCluster
              - Arn
            RoleArn: !GetAtt 
              - ECSTaskRole
              - Arn
            Id: id1
            EcsParameters:
              TaskCount: 1
              TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinitionWeekly

# monthly schedule  at midnight UTC     
ScheduledRuleMonthly: 
  Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "cron(00 00 1 * ? *)"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets:
          - Arn: !GetAtt 
              - MyCluster
              - Arn
            RoleArn: !GetAtt 
              - ECSTaskRole
              - Arn
            Id: id1
            EcsParameters:
              TaskCount: 1
              TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinitionMonthly
```

You can read more on event rule expressions on [amazon documentation website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).